# SCP error in QGIS 2.18.28

Tags: qgis, scp

I have installed SCP on QGIS 2.18.28 from the Plugins-manage and install plugins. When I tried opening it, it gave me an error of crashed dumped as shown below:

> minidump written to C:
>   \users\KLED\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis-20191030-151848-13368-13856-6551c2a73e.dmp

Answer (score 1):

QGIS 2.18 is no longer supported.

I would suggest upgrading to the latest LTR version 3.4.13.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I am most grateful

Comment: Hi @KulloEmmanuelDaata I'm glad that worked. If this answer helped please mark it as correct, by ticking the green check mark next to it.